# Assigning values from JavaScript to Java variable

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

How to assign a value from JavaScript to Java variable in the JSP page? Is it possible to do this?

The following is the javascript function:

```
function loadGroupMembers(beanArrayVal){
    document.getElementById("beanVal").value=beanArrayVal;

   ------------I have mentioned my requirement below --------------

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   int beanArrVal =beanArrayVal ;

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   ( or )

   %%%%%%%%%%

   c:set  var="beanvalue" value="${beanArrayVal}"

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%

}
```

Even I have assigned that `beanArrayVal` value in hidden input field too using id `beanVal` in the same above mentioned function. It's good enough even if is possible to assign value from this hidden field to JSTL variable.

Comment: Crossposted here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5421116.

Answer (score 2):

JS runs at the client machine. Java runs at the server machine. The only communication tool between those is HTTP. Java/JSP can generate/produce a HTML page and send it from server to client as a HTTP response, thus it can easily (pre)set Javascript variables by simply generating them as-is in the JSP template. But the other way round really requires a HTTP request from the client to the server. You can invoke HTTP requests synchronously by clicking a link or submitting a form, either manually or with little help of Javascript like `link.click()` or `form.submit()`. You can also invoke HTTP requests asynchronously with help of [Ajaxical](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) powers.

Long story short: let JS set it as a (hidden) input value / request parameter and send it to the server side by submitting the form with the (hidden) input value, or by invoking a link with the request parameter, or by firing an ajax request with a query string.

To learn more about the wall between Java/JSP and Javascript, you may find this article useful as well: [Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html).

Hope this clears a lot of things up and opens a new world for you.