# how to access the javascript variable in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to get JavaScript variable in jsp page scriptlet  i am trying alot its getting null value please  help me out.

Below mycode:

```
<script>
    function setacademicyear(ele){
        alert("ele"+ele);  
        request.setAttribute("ayear", ele);
    }

    <%
        if (request.getAttribute("ayear") != null) {
            String ayear1 = (String) request.getAttribute("ayear");
            System.out.println("ayear1ayear1ayear1" + ayear1);
            Academicyearmaster acy = (Academicyearmaster) ses.get(Academicyearmaster.class, Long.valueOf(ayear1));
            request.getSession().setAttribute("academicyear", acy);
        }%>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. JSP is processing on the server; then the client takes over and JavaScript can process. You cannot pass values from JavaScript to JSP except in a new request.

Imagine you were traveling to Moscow, and you ask your mother to remind you when you get there to find a way to get in touch with her. It's too late, she can't make contact, you have to remember it by yourself.

Comment: is there any other way to do it.i want that javascript variable in jsp scriplet could you please help me.

Comment: Not without a new request.

Comment: please could you explain me clearly i am not understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The javascript values aren't available on the server, in the servlet the jsp is translated to. You could make an AJAX call at runtime on the client. Also, please don't use scriptlets.

Comment: k k will try with Ajax call.thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can't but for alternate solutions you can look at this

[Assign JavaScript variable to Java Variable in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268356/assign-javascript-variable-to-java-variable-in-jsp)