# Define a string java with a js variable

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I need to define a java String in my jsp page thanks to a javascript variable, I know we can do the opposite with :

```
<% String str = "ok"; %>
var test="<%= str %>";
```

I wanted to know if something like this was possible :

```
var test="ok";
<% String str = %> test <% ; %>
```

I tried and it didn't worked but is there a way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: You can't do that with any server-side language... If you want to get a JavaScript variable value you'll need to send it using AJAX and receive using Java Web services.............

Comment: Related here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268356/assign-javascript-variable-to-java-variable-in-jsp