# How to convert JavaScript Variable to a JSP variable (int)

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to convert a javascript variable to a jsp variable like this

```
var correct=9;

<%int correct1%>=correct;
```

But it gives syntax error.

Comment: As far as I know, that's just not possible. At least not the way you want.

Comment: then what is the other method possible to achieve the target

Comment: You can allocate Java variables to Javascript to be run when the page is loaded but it can't go the other way around. If you wanted to pass a Javascript variable to JSP you'd have to make an Ajax request, open a new page or post a form.

Comment: this question has been answered many times, this is one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268356/assign-javascript-variable-to-java-variable-in-jsp

Comment: @psyLogic Very good, marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a data in your JavaScript code from JSP, but not reverse. Something like this:

```
var correct = <% int correct1 = 1; out.println(correct1); %>;
```

If you want to transfer JavaScript variable's value to the server side, you have to do It only with form data posting or ajax.

Sample:

**HTML file:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var correct = 9;

    $.ajax({

        url: 'your_jsp_file.jsp?correct=' + correct,
        method: 'get',
        success: function(result) {

            alert(result);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**JSP file (your_jsp_file.jsp):**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    int correct1;

    if (request.getParameter("correct") == null) {

        out.println("error");
    } 
    else {

        String param = request.getParameter("correct");

        if (param.matches("^[0-9]+$")) {

            correct1 = Integer.parseInt(param);
        }

        out.println("ok");
    }
%>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `out.println(correct)` be `out.println(correct1)`?

Comment: Shouldn't `'your_jsp_file.jsp?correct' = correct` be `'your_jsp_file.jsp?correct=' + correct`

Comment: @ErikKralj, thanks again :). I was so passionate about the process that did not pay attention to these errors

Comment: No problem, still missing an `=`. :D

Comment: @ErikKralj, checkmate :)